# Passagem de dados dispatcherServlet

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-mvc

Estou tentando realizar a exportação de dados do Log para o Excel só que está me apresentando o seguinte erro:

```
2019-03-18 10:16:16.022 ERROR 252 --- [nio-8080-exec-4] o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[.[dispatcherServlet]      : Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [/mv-fatur] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException] with root cause
```

A implementação está sendo feita da seguinte forma:

**LogAcessoUtil.java**

```
@Override
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
public List<LogAcessoDTO> getLogAcessoExcel(String cdCliente) {

    LocalDateTime agora = LocalDateTime.now();
    DateTimeFormatter formatterData = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd/MM/uuuu");
    String dataFormatada = formatterData.format(agora);

    StringBuilder sql = new StringBuilder();
    sql.append("select * from cli");

    List<LogAcessoDTO> returnQuery = em.createNativeQuery(sql.toString(), "LogAcessoDTOMapping").getResultList();

    return (List<LogAcessoDTO>) returnQuery;
}
```

**GlobalController.java**

```
@Autowired
private LogAcessoUtil logAcessoUtil;

@Autowired
private ExportFileService<LogAcessoDTO> exportFileServiceDetalhe;

@GetMapping("/getlogacesso/excel")
    public ResponseEntity<List<LogAcessoDTO>> getLogAcessoExcel(@RequestParam String cdCliente, HttpServletResponse response) {
        try {
            List<LogAcessoDTO> dtos = logAcessoUtil.getLogAcessoExcel(cdCliente);

            exportFileServiceDetalhe.exportExcelFile(dtos, response, "LogAcesso", "", "Cod. Cliente: " + cdCliente.toString());

            return new ResponseEntity<>(HttpStatus.OK);
        } catch (NoSuchMethodException | SecurityException | IllegalAccessException | IllegalArgumentException
            | InvocationTargetException | IOException ex) {
            log.error(ex.toString());
            return new ResponseEntity<>(HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Ikaro, você postou apenas uma linha da stacktrace, poderia por gentileza postar a stacktrace completa? Quanto mais detalhes sobre o problema melhor, e a stack completa e um dos pontos mais importantes para achar o problema.

Comment: Por gentileza poste também as demais classes envolvidas, como a `LogAcessoUtil` que provavelmente esta apresentando o problema. E também a forma como esta injetando os properties

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Os dados que você forneceu não são suficientes para ter certeza sobre a questão, mas a exceção lançada (`NullPointerException`) indica que está sendo invocado (chamado) um método por um objeto ou atribulo nulo.

Tenha certeza de que você instanciou (`new NomeDaClasse()`) ou anotou (com `@Autowired`, por exemplo) as variáveis/atributos `logAcessoUtil` e `exportFileServiceDetalhe` corretamente.

Os parâmetros `cdCliente` e `response` não deveriam ser nulos também.

Comment: Sim, estão anotados com @Autowired.

Comment: Como está sendo requisitado via GET (no brownser) estou passando o cdCliente, mas o HttpServletResponse não estou passando, acredito que seja isso. Mas o metodo que está pedindo esse parametro

Comment: Possivelmente é o parâmetro `response` que está nulo e gera a exceção. O método `exportExcelFile` é que pede um parâmetro do tipo `HttpServletResponse`? Ou o método `getLogAcessoExcel` está implementando a assinatura de uma interface?

Comment: Para ter certeza que o atributo `response` é nulo, basta adicionar `System.out.println(response);` (_debug_ manual) antes da linha que faz a invocação `exportFileServiceDetalhe.exportExcelFile(...)`.

Comment: "Possivelmente é o parâmetro response que está nulo e gera a exceção."
- Existem outros metodos fazendo a implementação dessa forma e não gera exception.

Comment: "O método exportExcelFile é que pede um parâmetro do tipo HttpServletResponse?"
- SIM

Comment: "Ou o método getLogAcessoExcel está implementando a assinatura de uma interface?"
- Esse metodo é responsável por ir no banco de dados trazer os dados e retornar um List que será passado para o metodo exportExcelFile

Comment: variavel RESPONSE teve o retorno: org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter$HeaderWriterResponse@76188ab8

Comment: Então `response` não é nula. E `dtos`, você já verificou se ela é nula?

Comment: sim, já verifiquei e tb não é `null`

Comment: Na verdade validei todos os parâmetros e nenhum é `null`

Comment: Eita! Então `logAcessoUtil.getLogAcessoExcel(cdCliente)` ou `exportFileServiceDetalhe.exportExcelFile(...)` está lançando `NullPointerException`. Circunde cada trecho em que esses dois métodos chamados com `try { ... } catch (NullPointerException e) { System.out.println("nomeDoMetodo"); }` e veja o que acontece.

Comment: Encontrei o `null` está vindo dessa propriedade: `String SAMPLE_PERSON_DATA_FILE_NAME = properties.getProperty(fileName + ".url");`

Comment: A bronca é, fiz um sysout da `Properties properties` e me retorna varios valores que não sei onde foram adicionados